# Set Error on ListView Item Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listData that I am using to create a listview .After that on click of a button I am updating my listview data for a particular item at one time. That I am storing after each update in an array updatedlistData. So now I want to compare both the previous array data i.e. listData and updatedlistData and where the values have not been updated on the item I want to show error .Please update value. So could I set the error on the item of the ListView? I tried to use this code:

**BaseAdapter Code** to create ListvIew

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            TextView value;
            value = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            value.setText(Value[position]);
            return (row);
        }
```

**OnClick** i am comparing

```
check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkData);
check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            for(int i=0;i< listData.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<updatedlistData;j++){
                    if(listData[i]==updatedlistData[j]){
                        View v=listView.getChildAt(i);
                        TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        tv.setError("Please change the data");
            } 
        }
    }           
});
```

So i am getting the **Exception**

```
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at com.example.activityMain.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-22 10:29:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(3546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So please help me to resolve this issue Thanks

Comment: Please paste full code here. because the proble is with your button id..

Comment: what is the "check" here???

Comment: what is on line 110??

Comment: But you didn't find the id for it...... So just check it..and update the code..

Comment: simple if i have to say i have to check onclick of button whether the previous value has been updated or not .This is what i asking .i have tow diffrent arrays one for previous values and other of updated values.If the item values is not changes i have to mark a error on that item

Comment: Yes..I understood....But where is the line for find id for button..??? That's why you got null pointer

Comment: updated pls check that is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

problem is nested forloop.You dont need two for loops.

```
for(int i=0;i< listData.length;i++){                
    if(listData[i]==updatedlistData[i]){
        View v=listView.getChildAt(i);
        TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setError("Please change the data");
    } 
}
```

Then you need to check if length of updatelistData is less than listdata, because in this case  when you access updatedlistData[i] it will give null pointer exception

Comment: both have the same length because i am just updating the value

Comment: you have not define check in getView().Add check definiton in getView